# Is it possible to capture some value for use inside of `splice` part of `reify` macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

For example, I have some list and want to iterate on it, and do macro transformation on each value:

```
reify {
  someIntListExpr.splice.foreach { i =>
    // transform is a macro of the form 'transform(c: Context)(i: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Unit]
    transform(i).splice
  }
}
```

But the compiler spits out error message:

```
found: Int
required: c.universe.Expr[Int]
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple cases this will do the trick:

```
someIntListExpr.splice.foreach { i =>
  transformImpl(c)(c.Expr[Int](Ident(newTermName("i")))).splice
}
```

Alternatively you can create method like this

```
def trans(i: Int): Unit = macro transform
```

and apply it:

```
reify {
  someIntListExpr.splice.foreach { i =>
    trans(i)
  }
}
```

Sometimes you can actually get `List[c.Expr[Unit]]`.

If your method (`def myMethod(l: List[Int]): unti = macro myMethodImpl`) is called like `myMethod(List(1, 2, x))` then you can get `List[c.Expr[Unit]]`:

```
def myMethodImpl(c: Context)(l: c.Expr[List[Int]]): ... = {
  import c.universe.Apply
  val es = l match {
    case Apply(_, l: List[c.Expr[Int]]) => l
  }
  ...
}
```